# Why is there an assertion error when the return value is the same?

Tags: python, return-value

So currently, I'm trying to make a simple function that takes in a list of numbers, and creates a new list containing the difference between each element and its subsequent element.

for example

`difference([1, 2, 5, 3])` would return `[1, 3, -2]`

now my code

```
def difference(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        i=0
        dif_list=[]
        while i < len(numbers)-1:
            dif_list.append(numbers[i+1]-numbers[i])
            i +=1
        if len(dif_list) == len(numbers)-1:
            return print(dif_list)
```

This does return the correct output, but when I try to use assertion to check it, it would say there's an assertion error.

`assert difference([1, 2, 5, 3]) == [1, 3, -2]`
gives out

```
<ipython-input-23-c9c23c8f4955> in <module>
----> 1 assert difference([1, 2, 5, 3]) == [1, 3, -2]
```

Does anyone now why is this happening?

Comment: "Now my code: does return the correct output" No, it does not. It *prints* the list that you are interested in. It *returns* `None`. Please think carefully about what `return print(dif_list)` actually means. Think about what it means to return a value, and about what the `print` function does. (Hint: `print` has *absolutely nothing to do with* returning.)

Comment: Why do you need two loops to iterate a unidimensional sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you return directly by deleting `print`, it will work:

```
def difference(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        i=0
        dif_list=[]
        while i < len(numbers)-1:
            dif_list.append(numbers[i+1]-numbers[i])
            i +=1
        if len(dif_list) == len(numbers)-1:
            return (dif_list)

assert difference([1,2,5,3]) == [1, 3, -2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def difference(numbers):
    dif_list=[]
    i = 0
    while i < len(numbers)-1:
        dif_list.append(numbers[i+1]-numbers[i])
        i +=1
    if len(dif_list) == len(numbers)-1:
        return dif_list

assert difference([1,2,5,3]) == [1, 3, -2]
print('pass')
```

Output: `pass`

The main pronblem was you were returning a print(), but I also moved your dif_list outside your for loop because it made sense. Hasn't altered much but that's where I'd put it. I'd probably refactor this a bit too but this runs now anyway.

EDIT - I couldn't help but refactor a bit because your `for` loop is totally unnecessary, it isn't doing anything.

Comment: Yea I realized I was doing a lot of really unnecessary bits to my code that are sometimes useless and sometimes bothersome. Thanks a lot!